# "'Output' only refers to a type, but is being used a value here" error

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

My object instantiation using a constructor declared for the interface:

```
let obj = new Output(cur.req, cur.type, cur.batchId, cur.rowId, dat2);
```

Model data structure

```
import { Data } from './data';

export interface Output {
 req: string;
 type: string;
 batchId: number;
 rowId: number;
 data: Array<Data>
}

export interface OutputConstructor {
 new (req: number, type: string, batchId: number, rowId: number, data:Array<Data>): Output;
 Clone(): Output;
}

export var Output: OutputConstructor;
```

Comment: Where did you actually declare Output? Currently, you have only posted the types so the error is telling you the exact problem.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve here? There are so many `Output`s in your Code, being used as an interface, class, variable name etc. which makes no sense at all.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`Output` is an [**interface**](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html), not a class. You can't directly instantiate an interface.

Answer (score 11):

Like another user said before, Output is an interface. So what you have to do to set the type is this:

```
let obj = {} as Output;
```